# On Area 51 new replies are shown to me though they are not replies for me

Tags: support, comments, area-51

I am the follower of the site *[Algorithms and Data Structures](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5120/algorithms-and-data-structures)*. When today I opened the site, I saw some new replies. I was confused to see the replies as they were not the replies of my question nor of my comments. Then why they are shown to me? Is this a bug or something else?

Please, tell me the rules for new replies on Area 51.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're notified of any changes to proposals you're following -- including new questions and comments on those questions.

You can still view comments directed only at you or your posts under the "responses" tab in [your profile page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/current):

> [image]